# Iterate multiple Enumerations and return a value in Elixir

Tags: elixir

I have the following set of Enum's as key value pairs

```
list_of_vehicles = [{"Toyota" => "Corolla"},{"Honda"=> "Insight"}]
list_of_colors = [{"C01"=> "Green"},{"C02"=> "White"}]
list_of_capacity = [{"S01"=> "4"},{"S02"=> "2"}]
```

I need to iterate through each list and generate a single string with all possibilities.

So far i have done following :

```
defp process_output(list_of_vehicles,list_of_colors,list_of_capacity)
    Enum.each(list_of_vehicles, fn{k,v}->     
          final_output = "#{k}"
          if(Enum.any?(list_of_colors)) do
            Enum.each(list_of_colors, fn{k,v}-> 
              final_output = final_output<>"#{k}"
              if(Enum.any?(list_of_capacity)) do
                Enum.each(list_of_capacity, fn{k,v}-> 
                  final_output = final_output <>"#{k}"
                end)
              else
                final_output 
              end
            end)
          else
            if(Enum.any?(list_of_capacity))do
              Enum.each(list_of_capacity, fn{k,v}-> 
                final_output = final_output<>"#{k}"
              end)
            else
              final_output 
            end
          end
        end)
end
```

I need to return this final output to another method.

```
list_of_outputs = process_output(vehicle_list,color_list_capacity_list)
```

But could not find a way to generate the final output list

Desired O/P

```
["ToyotaC01S01","ToyotaC01S02","ToyotaC02S01","ToyotaC02S02",
 "HondaC01S01","HondaC01S02","HondaC02S01","HondaC02S02",...etc]
```

Comment: Please show us the desired input and the desired output. Did I properly understand you just need to concatenate all the keys?

Comment: yes @mudasobwa, i need to concatenate all the keys and return a list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Scoping.** Scoping matters in Elixir very much. One can not bind a variable inside a `do` block and expect it would be visible from outside. Your rebound `final_output` would be discarded as the scope of `each` is exited.

**Redundancy.**

```rb
if Enum.any?(list), do: Enum.each(...)
```

`if` here is redundant, since `Enum.each([])` is a noop.

**Elixir warnings.** Read what Elixir says during the compilation process and follow advices. If the variable is unused, prepend it with an underscore.

**Control flow.** In functional programming one mainly uses `map`-`reduce` rather than plain loops. As you might notice, there is neither `for` nor `while` loops available in Elixir. That is on purpose and one should not try to simulate their behavior with `Enum.each`. It won’t work.

**The summing up:**

```rb
list_of_vehicles = [{"Toyota", "Corolla"}, {"Honda", "Insight"}]
list_of_colors = [{"C01", "Green"}, {"C02", "White"}]
list_of_capacities = [{"S01", "4"}, {"S02", "2"}]

for {vehicle, _} <- list_of_vehicles,
    {color, _} <- list_of_colors,
    {capacity, _}  <- list_of_capacities,
do: vehicle <> color <> capacity

#⇒ ["ToyotaC01S01", "ToyotaC01S02", "ToyotaC02S01", "ToyotaC02S02",
#   "HondaC01S01", "HondaC01S02", "HondaC02S01", "HondaC02S02"]
```

Here we use [`Kernel.SpecialForms.for/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#for/1) comprehension.

Please note, I have corrected the input to be Elixir-valid tuples.

Comment: When the number of items in the lists are not equal, the output doesn't return all the combinations. Is there any solution for that?

Comment: Of course, it does. Comprehension returns all the combinations, despite the lengths of the input.

Answer (score 0):

If You want to get possibilities of all keys of your desire variables, then you can get all possibilities by using 3 nested loop.

for example

```
Enum.map(list_of_vehicles,
  fn v -> (
    Enum.map(list_of_colors,
     fn c -> (
      Enum.map(list_of_capacities,
       fn cap ->(
        List.first(Map.keys v)<> List.first(Map.keys c) <> List.first(Map.keys cap))
       end)
      )
     end)
    )
  end
  )
|> List.flatten
```

After looping you can flatten all your list and you will get desire output

```
#["ToyotaC01S01", "ToyotaC01S02", "ToyotaC02S01", "ToyotaC02S02", "HondaC01S01",
 "HondaC01S02", "HondaC02S01", "HondaC02S02"]
```

Let me know if you didn't get the answer